# Withdraw NFT from PDA/ TokenAccount Anchor-lang

Tags: anchor, rust, pda, nft, anchor-spl

That is what am i doing, transferring my NFTs to `TokenAccount` with  `authority` as `stake_account` which is a PDA. How can I tranfer NFTs back to a certian wallet in `anchor-lang`.

```
use anchor_spl::token::{ Token, TokenAccount, Transfer }
```

Token Account:

```
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        seeds = [mint.key().as_ref(), b"nfts_vault_seed", from.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        //space = 82,
        payer = from, 
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = stake_account, //THIS authority is PDA  
    )]
    pub nfts_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

Transfer NFT to `TokenAccount`:

```
token::transfer(
       CpiContext::new(
          ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
          token::Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.nfts_vault.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
          }
       ), 1
)?;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code snippet to transfer tokens from a token account with PDA authority:

```
let config_bump = ctx.accounts.config.bump;
let config_seeds = &[
    "config".as_bytes().as_ref(),
     ctx.accounts.config.admin.as_ref(),
     &[config_bump]
];
let signer = &[&config_seeds[..]];
        
anchor_spl::token::transfer(
    CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.staking_pool.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.staker_token_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.config.to_account_info(),
         }
    ).with_signer(signer),
    1
)?;
```

Here a transfer is being made from `staking_pool` account to `staker_token_account`. Since `staking_pool` is owned by a PDA(`config`) which can't sign client-side, we add `.with_signer()` to our CpiContext.

Our signer is derived from the seeds and bump of the `config` account.

Comment: Thanks, buddy. Can you share your ```config``` PDA snippet? My PDA does not have ```to_account_info()```.

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy. I redeployed the Solana Program with your provided solution and all problems were solved.